# How to fill an array of ints while keeping its order?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, console-application

I'm trying to do a simple exercise where I want to fill an array of ints, from user inputs, and keep the inputs in order so there's no need to sort the array after user is done.

Assume the state of the array is something like this: { 3, 5, 7, 8, 9,-,-,-,-,- } ( - means empty)

Now in this state, for example, if you enter 6, all elements after arr[1] are supposed to move one place forward so that 6 can be placed in arr[2].

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool ok = true;
    int x       // the input
        , n = 0 // to keep track of numbers already in the array
        , i, j  // to iterate in loops
        , arr[10];

    cout << "Enter 10 numbers: \n";
    while (cin >> x) {
        if (n == 0) { arr[n] = x; n++; } // for the first entry.

        else if (x < arr[0]) { // is x lower than the first element in the array?
            for (i = n; i > 0; i--)
                arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
            arr[0] = x; n++;
        }

        else if (x > arr[n - 1]) { // is x greater than the top of already addded 
                                   // elements to the array?
            arr[n] = x; n++;
        }

        else { // when x is in between of elements. Also I think the problem is here.
            for (i = 0; i < n && ok; i++)
                if (x > arr[i] && x < arr[i + 1]) {
                    for (j = n; j > i + 1; j--)
                        arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
                    ok = false;
                }
            arr[i + 1] = x; n++;
        }

        if (n == 10) break; // if you reached to end of the array, break while.
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
}
```

The're a lot of issues with this code but for one when I try to enter: 1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 the program does not move the 10 to the end of array, and it outputs: 1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.

Comment: what you are speaking of is 'container'. You can use binary trees to do that, but the best is the AVL tree. You can still do that like that, but it's way more efficient to use trees instead. There are already containers in the stl, see Pustovalov comment.

Comment: Why don't you want to use std::set which automatically sorts it's values? Or you have to use C-style array?

Comment: `std::set<int> arr; while (cin >> x) arr.insert(x);`  A 3-liner.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant AVL is not the best. RB faster.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie std::multiset

Comment: I said that it is an "exercise." I know that there are _far_ more efficient ways to do what I intend, but I'm learning and I just want to know the issue with my code.

Comment: @SashaMN: AVL is more rigidly balanced than red–black trees, leading to slower insertion and removal but faster retrieval (wikipédia).

Comment: set `ok` to `true` value at the beginning of while iteration (inside while).

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant "slower insertion and removal" - key words here.

Comment: @Eternal_ink *I just want to know the issue with my code.* -- Have you used the debugger to see where you are going wrong?  Also, you should be testing fewer numbers.  Try it with 2 or 3 numbers, maybe 4.  Using 10 numbers will make it more difficult for you to keep track of where you're going wrong.

Comment: @SashaMN: both are viable. Still way better than using a simple binary tree :) Sdt::map seems to implement RB.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant because RB tree works faster. std::set implements RB tree too.

Comment: @SelçukCihan I did that but no difference.

Comment: @SashaMN: it's not better, it's better for insert/removal, not for searching. RB are easier to implement than AVL too.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant try to test both implementations on your own computer.

Comment: @SashaMN: I have both and it's clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the incrementation step of a for-loop is always performed when the previous execution condtion was true.

```
    for (i = 0; i < n && ok; i++) // i is incremented
        if (x > arr[i] && x < arr[i + 1]) {
            for (j = n; j > i + 1; j--)
                arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
            ok = false;
        }
    arr[i + 1] = x; n++;
```

So after inserting "2" the condition of the for-loop is true:

```
for (i = 0; i < n && ok; i++)
```

Afterwards the body of the for-loop is executed and i is incremented.
Now the condition is checked again and is evaluated to false, but nevertheless i is 1 instead of the expected value 0.

So after performing

```
    arr[i + 1] = x; n++;
```

your array looks like:
[1] [10] [2]

Comment: Kind people wrote me some very good answers/ideas here, but I marked yours as the _answer_ because what you pointed out was the _exact error_ of my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a raw array you could use a `std::vector` in combination with `std::upper_bound` and use the following construct for every user input:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::vector<T>::iterator insertInOrder(std::vector<T> &v, T const &val){
  auto it = std::upper_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), val);
  v.insert(it, val);

  return it;
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b405755a5baae9d)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's your homework and you're not allowed to use vectors with  `vector::insert()`, nor other appropriate standard container or algorithms.

I propose to simplify the algorithm by using one single general appraoch:  try to find the first element in the array to which x is slower.  If it is found, insert x at the correct place, otherwise, add it at the end:

```
while (cin >> x) {
    for (i=0, ok=false; i<n; i++ ) { // iterate for the general case
        if (x < arr[i]) {  // find first wher x is lower
            for (j = n; j>i; j--)  // move remaining elements
                arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
            arr[i] = x;
            n++;
            ok = true;   // we've found the place and inserted x
            break; 
        }
    }
    if (!ok) {   // if we didn't insert until now, we have to add it at the end
        if (n<arrsize)
            arr[n++] = x; 
        else cerr << "Array full "<<endl; 
    }
}
```

Here the **[live demo](http://ideone.com/SXGT5B)** (arrsize is a const defined to 10).

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
        for (i = 0; i < n && ok; i++)
            if (x > arr[i] && x < arr[i + 1]) {
                for (j = n; j > i + 1; j--)
                    arr[j] = arr[j - 1];

                // All elements moved - get out of the for-loop
                break;
            }
        arr[i + 1] = x; n++;
```

However, the line

```
            if (x > arr[i] && x < arr[i + 1]) {
```

will give you problem as well.

If your array holds

```
2, 3, 4
```

and the next input is 3, the if-statement will never become true and the program will fail.

Comment: Yeah, `break;` !!! Thank you.
No, I know. From the start I was aiming only for non-equal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

arrays are just bad for this kind of thing..
consider using a linked list,
you make a Node class that contains a value and pointer to next node:

```
class Node{
    int number;
    Node *nextNode;
}
```

and a bit more code for the List class to handle theme, 
you will find it a lot easier to insert a node in betwin tow other nodes,
rather then moving the array a thousand times.

better information -> http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson15.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help, so

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void inputInOrder(int *arr, int num){

    // Start from the end of array.
    // If newly added element is smaller then the element before it swap them.

    for(int i(num); i > 0; i--)
        if(arr[i] < arr[i-1])
            std::swap(arr[i], arr[i-1]);
        else break;
    }


int main()
{

    int n;
    cout << "Number of elements: ";
    cin >> n;


    int *arr = new int[n];

    int input(0);

    for(int i(0); i < n; ++i){
        cout << "Insert element: ";
        cin >> input;
        arr[i] = input;  // you add a new element to the end of array
        // call a function that will move newly added element to the right place
        inputInOrder(arr, i);
    }

    for(int i(0); i < n; ++i)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";

    delete[] arr;

    return 0;
}
```